# getting out of the society

Tags: sentence-patterns

What does "Discrimination  which prevents people from getting out
of their society what they contribute is unjust" mean in the following context.

> The nonwhites live in American society, fight for American society in
>   disproportionate numbers and contribute cheap labour to American
>   society, thereby enabling others to live disproportionately well. But
>   the nonwhites do not share in  the benefits of the American
>   society in which they live and for which they fight and to which they
>   contribute. 41% of  Negroes fall below the poverty line as compared
>   with 12% of whites. Infant mortality is three times as high among 
>   nonwhite babies as among white. Whereas, Negroes make up 11% of the
>   nation’s work force, they have but 6% of the  nation’s technical and
>   professional jobs, 3% of the managerial jobs, and 6% of jobs in
>   skilled trades. **Discrimination  which prevents people from getting out
>   of their society what they contribute is unjust.** The disproportionate
>   number of African-American who fall below the poverty line is being
>   cited as evidence that  minorities in America are not treated equally
>   to the White majority.

---

Comment: See e.g. Collins, *[get out](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-out)*: *to gain or receive something, esp something of significance or value, "you get out of life what you put into it."*

Comment: @choster Thank you. I got an answer and I got it. Your comment is useful as well. btw I thought it completely different like " changing social class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing is perhaps slightly clumsy, and indeed *which* is used incorrectly here, according to prescriptionist grammar. If I reword it as follows, does that help?

> Discrimination [of the sort] that prevents people from getting out of their society that which they contribute is unjust.

—or—

> Discrimination [of the sort] that prevents people from getting back from society what they contribute [to society] is unjust.

Reading the sentence with a slight pause before the "is unjust" may help parse it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. "getting out of" or as you wrote "getting back from" means " to share in" ..Do you think the original sentence should have had  " to" after the word "contribute" in reference to the word "society"  because "to contribute" needs a preposition mostly.

Comment: The original sentence could have "to it" (but not merely "to") after "contribute", and that would probably make it clearer, yes. And yes, that's more or less what "getting out of" means – the idea is that you are extracting value from society in return for the work you've contributed to it.

Comment: how about this one. Does it work  "Discrimination which prevents people from getting out of their society to what they contribute is unjust"

Comment: The "to" has no place in that sentence. You could add "to it" after "contribute" to improve clarity, but that's it. Also, the "which" should be a "that" really, but people will understand you regardless, I think.